# How to only on field history enable object in apex?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, apexrest, schema

We have 5 objects. In these objects, we are only tracking 3 objects field history,

How can I query on enable history objects

How how to get only field history enabled object Name

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()` and see if the History table for the correspoding object exists.

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> sch = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

if(sch.containsKey('AccountHistory')){
    System.debug('Contains Account History');
}
if(sch.containsKey('Application__History')){
    System.debug('Contains Application History');
}
if(sch.containsKey('NonExistantObject__History')){
    System.debug('Contains Non Existant Object History');
}
```